# Add multiple titles on highchart piechart hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I have to display two titles in highCharts piechart on hover ( view image ) [image: HighCharts_PieChart_Issue]

I want to display the percentage value on hover and i have the percentage calculated already into an array.

And I wish to just display the percentage against the specified product.

When I put it through, I get all values as percentage in all products ( please refer fiddle )

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ve53msex/)

Here is a piece of code that I tried :

```
var anewVar = [0.0, 17.6, 0.0, 0.0, 6.6, 34.3, 17.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 23.9] // just a dummy array, actually want to display the percentage that we get ( for eg, mustard oil is 17.6 % ) on hover with amount( as shown )

Highcharts.chart('pieholder', {
    chart: {
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Productwise Sale ( Amt )'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            size: '50%',
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Percent : ' + anewVar + ' <br> Amount',
        colorByPoint: true,
        color: ['#AA4643'],
        data: [{
            name: 'Coconut Oil',
            y: 14211
        }, {
            name: 'ALMOND OIL',
            y: 0
        }, {
            name: 'Oil',
            y: 312
        }, {
            name: 'Special Oil',
            y: 0
        }, {
            name: 'Special Combo Offer',
            y: 0
        }, {
            name: 'Dairy Special',
            y: 10156
        }, {
            name: 'Sunflower Oil',
            y: 20390
        }, {
            name: 'Dairy Taaza Pure Milk ',
            y: 3937
        }, {
            name: 'JASMINE OIL',
            y: 0
        }, {
            name: 'AMLA OIL',
            y: 0
        }, {
            name: 'Mustard Oil',
            y: 10432
        }, {
            name: 'New Oil',
            y: 0,

        }]
    }]
});
```

The percentage that appears on each title gets calculated dynamically by highCharts (hope so!, just assuming) but I have it calculated in an array and wish to display it against the product when hovered over ( like it gets displayed against the title, I want it to display percentage when hovered over it too )

Can anyone help me how to do so ?

Or is there any other way as to how can I achieve it ?

> **Have searched thoroughly on stack overflow, github but couldn't find a solution. All the answers mentioned had either two separate charts
>   or something different from what my requirement is**
>
> **NOTE : Those who downVote, please comment or answer.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [tooltip.formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter)

```
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b><br> ' + 'Percentage: ' + this.percentage.toFixed(1) + ' %<br>' + 'Amount: ' + this.y;
    }
  },
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ve53msex/3/)

Comment: Thanks a ton mate @Deep 3015 !